# Why doesn't IN operator work on the result returned by subquery ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, subquery

Why doesn't operator work i.e. returns nothing?

```
Select * from complaints where Code 
IN 
(select
   distinct  
    stuff((
        select ',' + QUOTENAME(cs.Code,'''')
        from MC_Complaints.dbo.Complaints cs where cs.OverDue= 1
        order by cs.Code asc
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as codeslist
from MC_Complaints.dbo.Complaints cs)
```

This query

```
select
   distinct  
    stuff((
        select ',' + QUOTENAME(cs.Code,'''')
        from MC_Complaints.dbo.Complaints cs where cs.OverDue= 1
        order by cs.Code asc
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as codeslist
from MC_Complaints.dbo.Complaints cs
```

returns

```
'LG/17/05/0','LG/17/05/2','LG/17/05/3','Local Council Board/17/05/1','Local Council Board/17/05/10','Local Council Board/17/05/11'
```

but IN doesn't pick any record but when I put these codes in IN operator i.e.

```
Select * from complaints where Code in 
(
    'LG/17/05/0','LG/17/05/2','LG/17/05/3','Local Council Board/17/05/1','Local Council Board/17/05/10','Local Council Board/17/05/11'
)
```

then it works surprisingly but not when returned but the subquery. Why ?

Comment: A string *containing* quote characters and commas is *different* from multiple strings *separated* by commas. As true in T-SQL as in most other programming languages. Why are you doing `DISTINCT` and converting to this string anyway - `IN` supports having a subquery directly.

Comment: I.e. it looks like your whole query could just be `Select * from complaints where Code in (select Code from MC_Complaints.dbo.Complaints where cs.OverDue= 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

The result from the `stuff()` is a *string*.  Just because the string happens to contain commas does not mean that it is a list of values.  The string `'A,B,C'` is quite different from the list `'A', 'B', 'C'`.

The good news is that this can greatly simplify your logic:

```
Select c.*
from complaints c
where c.code in (select cs.Code
                 from MC_Complaints.dbo.Complaints cs
                 where cs.OverDue = 1
                );
```

Two more points.  First, your `in` expression is followed by a column alias (`codelist`).  That is not permitted syntax.

Second, the relevant comparison would be:

```
where cCode in (
    '''LG/17/05/0'',''LG/17/05/2'',''LG/17/05/3'',''Local Council Board/17/05/1'',''Local Council Board/17/05/10'',''Local Council Board/17/05/11'''
      )
```

That is an `in` list that has a single string value.

Comment: Can you please share the reason behind using Double quotes instead of single quotes with IN clause?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . I'm trying to point out that the value is not a single string.

Comment: But i think that can be rewritten as 

`where cCode in (
    'LG/17/05/0','LG/17/05/2','LG/17/05/3','Local Council Board/17/05/1','Local Council Board/17/05/10','Local Council Board/17/05/11')`

and this is same as what you have suggested.